# "at the age of" vs "at age"

Tags: sentence

Which sentence sounds better/more natural?

> She first became aware of it at the age of five.

or

> She first became aware of it at age five.

Comment: I encounter "She was his age", why there is no "at"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference is in register: they're both equally valid in professional writing. Writing “at the age of five” is more formal, while “at age five” is more technical or direct.

Modern and effective language tends towards brevity, so the second wins in that sense.

Comment: the sentence is intended for a novel. So I guess number two.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use in formally the first one better and second one is also correct but it should be not so formal to speak.

So speak this.

> She first became aware of it at the age of five.

Comment: When you say "to use in formally"? Do you mean "to use *it* formally" or "to use it *informally*"?